# Executing dynamic SQL in Postgres 8.2

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a table inside a function using dynamic SQL and immediately copy it into another table.

```
execute 'create table week_temp as 
    select w.*, ww.*
    from employer_weekly w
    left join employer_weekly_' || $1 || '_2 ww
        on w.w_employer::int = ww.emp_' || $1 || '::int';

drop table if exists employer_weekly;
create table employer_weekly as select * from week_temp;
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Error : ERROR:  relation with OID 9288742 does not exist
>
> CONTEXT: SQL statement "create table employer_weekly as select * from
> week_temp"

Checking manually, I can see week_temp and can access it correctly.

Would appreciate any clues!

Comment: Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten. You should upgrade to a maintained (=supported version) now.

Answer (score 0):

What @a_horse_with_no_name said.

But - the problem you are seeing is that the non-dynamic statements in your function are being compiled. This means the "FROM week_temp" is looking at an older version of week_temp that no longer exists. Make that statement dynamic SQL too and it should work.